# How can I display a text field in Looker Studio

Tags: looker-studio

This should be an easy one.  I made a text by concatenating some data but I can't figure out how to display it in the UI.  All I need to do is show this, in the Looker Studio UI.

[image]

[image]

When I try to use it as a metric for a Scorecard it shows it as CTO.

[image]

I'm new to Looker Studio and any help would be great.

Comment: Try the table chart while unselecting the header, row numbers & pagination

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your 1st screenshot, it appears that your calculated field `TopRightDates` will be considered as a String/ Text data type since it includes string/ text values (*"Period: ", " -> "*).

You can try placing this data field in your dimensions instead of the metrics. The reason why it is marked as `CTD` (Count Distinct) is because that is the only way Looker Studio can aggregate non-numeric data.

The metrics section usually involves numerical data fields that can be mathematically aggregated such as SUM, AVERAGE, MAX, etc...

I hope my answer helped you.